# When I draw my SVG contents to a canvas, the SVG is cropped

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, drawing

I have a bunch of lines of SVG text that I need to draw to a canvas.  I'm converting my SVG object into an SVG data URI, applying that to an image's source, and then drawing that image to the canvas, but it's clipping the text after a certain width and height for some reason.

I know the issue isn't the canvas size because I'm also drawing other images to the canvas first (that're way wider and taller than the text) with no problems.  Another weird thing is, if I take the image and append it to the body, it comes out perfectly.

```
var imageText = new Image();
imageText.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa($("#text_container").html());
imageText.onload = function() { context.drawImage(imageText, 0, 0); };
```

#text_container is my DIV that holds all the SVG code.

EDIT: To give more detail, here's a comment I wrote below: I'm building a JS application that lets users create a custom football.  You can change different colors and features of the ball and text, so it boils down to several DIVs with some SVG text (because the text goes along an arc'd path).  I can take the background-images of the DIVs and draw it onto the canvas just fine, to create the football.  I have problems when I try to draw the text onto the canvas because it's being cropped.  Then I'm going to take that canvas element and turn it into a PNG for the user to save.

I moved the text up and to the left more so you could see the cropping better.  The ball draws just fine, as you can see.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar4lP.png

Comment: Why are you doing that? All browsers that support canvas support SVG as well.

Comment: I'm building a JS application that lets users create a custom football.  You can change different colors and features of the ball and text, so it boils down to several DIVs with some SVG text (because the text goes along an arc'd path).  I can take the background-images of the DIVs and draw it onto the canvas just fine, to create the football.  I have problems when I try to draw the text onto the canvas because it's being cropped.  Then I'm going to take that canvas element and turn it into a PNG for the user to save.

Answer (score 1):

I had this *exact* same problem, but I think I just found the solution.

It's not enough just to set a `width` and a `height` on your SVG element. Apparently, you also need to set the `viewBox`:

```
<svg width="720" height="400" viewBox="0 0 720 400"></svg>
```

This should render the image correctly on the canvas. :)

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark.... does `drawImage()` have some sort of size parameters you can set? Maybe it has a default that it's drawing to in size, then clipping the rest. Just a thought...

It could also be that, since your image is dynamically created, there's some sort of image size parameters that are missing that would normally be included in say a .jpg, which the `drawImage()` function could be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `context` is your canvas' RenderingContext ("2D"), you should include the "destiny width" and  "destiny height" parameters on your [context.drawImage()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) function:

```
context.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dw, dh)
```

If myCanvas is the id of your canvas object (and $ is jQuery's function), you can call:

```
var dw = $('myCanvas').width();
var dh = $('myCanvas').height();
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, dw, dh);
```

This will scale the image in order to fit the whole canvas. My advice is to first "see" what the svg image is (i.e. add it to the body and measure in which coordinates the text is: sx, sy, sw and sh, in the link above), because you probably has to crop it "on purpose" in order to position it where you want:

```
context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
```

Comment: No dice.  It ended up taking the chunk of text and blowing it up.